# How do you get hgsubversion working?

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsubversion

The online documentation for hgsubversion sucks, IMO (I hate to say that). I've been following the instructions in the [Quick Start](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/hgsubversion.html#id4).

What have I done?

1. I installed Mercurial:

   D:\repos\experimental>hg --version
   Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.6)
2. I installed TortoiseHg to match the Mercurial version.
3. I downloaded the hgsubversion repository:

   D:\devapps> hg clone http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion
4. I modified my .hgrc as follows:

   [extensions]
   hgsubversion=D:\devapps\hgsubversion\hgsubversion

   D:\repos\experimental>hg help hgsubversion
   hgsubversion extension - integration with Subversion repositories

   hgsubversion is an extension for Mercurial that allows it to act as a Subversion client, offering fast, incremental and bidirectional synchronisation.
5. I installed [PySVN for Python 2.5](http://pysvn.tigris.org/files/documents/1233/45660/py25-pysvn-svn156-1.7.0-1177.exe).
6. I tried to clone an SVN repository:

   ...> hg clone http://path/to/repository/ repository-hg

And I got the following result:

```
...
abort: Subversion 1.5.0 or later required, but no bindings were found!
```

WTF? There's nothing in the instructions I'm following that tells you how to install this. Any help is greatly appreciated!! (I just want a way to work without SVN as much as possible - PLEASE HELP!).

Comment: well, i'm done with this sh!t ... when it doesn't require being a python guru to use, maybe i'll give it a shot ... but for now, i'm going to find another way to hack my *java* sources other than by debugging obscure python problems ... -- a bitter man

Comment: Voting up. I wasted too many days on this as well. I think you have to compile the SWIG bindings FROM SOURCE! It's stuff like this that keeps me away from *nix. :(

Comment: i figured out a way to get this working without compiling from source ... see the answer I posted ... basically remove the regular Mercurial install from the PATH and leave only TortoiseHg ...

Comment: Yes, as the Quick Start says, the bindings are bundled with TortoiseHg so you're all set after installing that and cloning the repository. See also http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/manual/1.1/nonhg.html#hgsubversion-svn which again explains that you only need to clone the hgsubversion repository.

Comment: In case anyone has the same problem as me: Since THG 3.4 the subversion bindings are no longer bundled. They have to be downloaded and installed separately. See: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/libsvn

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As described in my [blog post](http://www.upthescala.com/2010/07/goal-of-all-this-is-to-get-hgsubversion.html), you need to do the following to get this working:

- Remove the /path/to/Mercurial from your PATH variable
- leave only /path/to/TortoiseHg on the PATH

Now the TortoiseHg binary will be used when you invoke 'hg' from the command line and the hgsubversion extension will work as advertised!

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Actually I was about to suggest you did that, as installing both Mercurial and TortoiseHg is redundant, as the latter packages the former.

Anyway, +1, and glad you found the way out. And thanks for your blog post, too.

Comment: TortoiseHg no longer includes bindings. -- https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/libsvn

Comment: Blog link is dead

Comment: Today the problem is most likely to simply come from the fact TortoiseHg no longer includes bindings, and the best is to install them from the page above, rather than using this procedure.

Answer (score 3):

I don't actually know much about Windows, but my understanding is that TortoiseHG should bundle everything you need. They have [some instructions](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/1.0/nonhg.html#hgsubversion-svn) that it looks like you already followed, but maybe you can ask on [their mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/tortoisehg-discuss) for some help? They're pretty much the best ones to follow up with.

The SWIG bindings are currently required, but we're close to having support for some other bindings (not PySVN, subvertpy) that should be less hard to install. I can't make any solid claims about how easy/hard those will be on Windows since I have no way of testing that.

Answer (score 3):

After digging same problem, I've found a good instruction on bitbucket, which was a solution for correct installing of python bindings.
https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/libsvn

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem and just gave up. The major problem is that there are no precompiled win32 Python SWIG bindings for recent versions of SVN.

You may want to see if the hgsvn tools will do what you need: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion#With_hgsvn

It's not a proper extenstion, just a bundle of three tools: `hgimportsvn`, `hgpullsvn`, and `hgpushsvn`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Python can't find the Subversion bindings.

If you can, try to install TortoiseHg, which bundles them. Maybe because I had it installed, I had no problems at all using hgsubversion.

Comment: Hmm... what happens if you fire up python's interactive interpreter and try to "from svn import client"?

You are seeing this error because "from svn import *something*" does not succeed in hgsubversion code, as it seems from this http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/src/aafbf0d40dc2/hgsubversion/svnwrap/svn_swig_wrapper.py#cl-27

Comment: D:\repos\experimental>python
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import from svn client
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import from svn client
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from svn import client
>>>

Comment: seemed to work ...

>>> from svn import client
>>> from svn import core
>>> core.SVN_VER_MAJOR
1
>>> core.SVN_VER_MINOR
5
>>> core.SVN_VER_MICRO
3
>>>

Comment: i have both 2.5 and 3.x of python installed ... currently uninstalling the latter in case that is causing conflicts :)

Comment: Yes, that *might* be the cause. Sadly I'm no python expert :(

Comment: What's the output of "svn --version --quiet"?

Comment: TortoiseHg no longer includes SVN bindings.